# Anonymous types in C++

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there is any equivalent, or a way to fake, C# style anonymous types in C++.  I'm using gcc 4.6 so any parts of C++0x it supports can be used.

Comment: Having a type without a name is surely not your end goal. What is your actual problem? What C# problem do you use anonymous types to solve?

Comment: @Rob: Anonymous types are used in C# to allow you to extract multiple specific pieces of information from LINQ queries. C++ doesn't have anything like LINQ queries, so I'm not sure what problem you'd use them for in C++.

Answer (score 5):

If you’re looking for a container that can hold a “bag” of different types, the closest analog would be [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

Answer (score 2):

You can sort of fake it with a `std::map<std::string, boost::any>`, but that's really not the same. There's no way to get anything truly like C# 3+'s anonymous types in C++.

Anonymous types are really only useful for LINQ anyway, and C++ doesn't support anything like that either, so it's unlikely that such would be useful anyway.